# Shortest code to determine if a string is a palindrome

Tags: code-golf, palindrome, decision-problem

A *palindrome* is some string that is spelled the same way both backwards and forwards.  For instance, 'Eva, can I stab bats in a cave?' is a palindrome (EVACANISTAB | BATSINACAVE)

For this code golf, using the language of your choice, determine if a given string is a palindrome or not.

*Edge Cases:*

- Punctuation is not counted towards palindrominess.
- Control characters are not counted towards palindrominess.
- Whitespace is not counted towards palindrominess.
- Numbers are counted towards palindrominess.
- Case in this challenge is not counted towards palindrominess.
- There is no limit to the length of strings to evaluate, except for what is imposed by your language of choice.
- For this challenge, limit yourself to the ASCII character set.

*Technical Requirements:*

- Only method bodies are needed; additional things like method signatures, data structure declarations, etc. do not count towards the victory requirement.
- Code must compile or interpret without compile-time errors or exceptions.
- Code must not throw any unhandled exceptions or crash.  (Almost needless to say.  Almost.)
- Code must return some value indicating palindrominess.  The data type depends on the language you use (e.g. a C# user might use a `bool`, whereas a JavaScript user could use a `var`.)
- You may not write your own interpreter that performs this task as a 'native' capability so you can 'golf' a near-winning score.  (Hopefully needless to say.)

*Victory Condition:*

- The shortest code in characters wins.

## *Current Leader: tmartin (k, 25 characters)*

...Want the magic green check mark by *your* answer?  Beat this guy's answer!

Comment: Is I/O a part of the challenge, or a function body will do?

Comment: What about case? Non-ASCII and control characters?

Comment: @PeterTaylor based on the example, case should be ignored. I assume control characters are punctuation.

Comment: Updated with clarifications per comments.

Comment: The "breadcrumbs" for showing how the work is refined are available site-wide in all answers via revision history. There's no need to have a full history visible in the current version of the answer.

Comment: Could you clarify `Code must not throw any unhandled exceptions or crash.` please? Should there be no exceptions for any input or any valid input?

Comment: No exceptional states for any input; the edge case descriptions *should* ensure that the given code is immune to any gotchas (emphasis on *should*.)

Comment: 2 hours for code golf? Some alternatives seem shorter in the few hours since... That's a mite quick, or am I missing something?

Comment: @WernerCD I'm sure the OP will change who gets the green tick when he comes back to check on the new responses.

Comment: Not specifying a language really trivialises this challenge for me. As seen below, interpreted languages with a focus on high order text manipulation functions always get the shortest results.

What is to stop me throwing together my own interpreter with a single function, ip(). My compete algorithm is now 'ip:i'. 4 characters. done.

Comment: @Gusdor see [J and GolfScript suck all the enjoyment out of Code Golf](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/286/j-and-golfscript-suck-all-the-enjoyment-out-of-code-golf) and [Language Handicap](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/185/language-handicap) and related questions on this site's meta.

Comment: Gareth: You're right, I do.
Gusdor: I would think 'no custom language' is an implicit rule.  Of course, you bring up a fair point.
WernerCD: I do keep an eye on this, but I have to sleep (I am a mere mortal.)

Comment: I was under the impression that the `green tick` can't be changed after a set amount of time. Different between sites? My misunderstanding? If you can change the green tick to keep current with the leader, then I stand corrected :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### K, 25

```
{x~|x:_x@&x in,/.Q`a`A`n}
```

.

```
k){x~|x:_x@&x in,/.Q`a`A`n}"Eva, can I stab bats in a cave?"
1b
```

Comment: Looks like a mixture of Q and k :P

Comment: Well, I wouldn't exactly call .Q.A etc q. They're just string wrappers, there's no real k code underneath them. Now, if I said .q.inter I'd be in trouble.

Comment: I guess it's a case of quibbling over semantics but they are defined in q.k

Comment: Could just say Q for 31: `{x~(|)x:(_)x inter(,/).Q\`a\`A\`n}`

Comment: i know this is very old but... you can save 1 byte with ```{#|:\_x@&x in,/.Q`a`A`n}``` , where 1 is true and 2 is false

Answer (score 25):

### Perl, 26 char

```
s/_|\W//g;uc eq reverse uc
```

Evaluates to 1 when `$_` is a palindrome, `""` (one of Perl's false values) when it is not.

Sample usage:

```
sub palin {
    s/_|\W//g;uc eq reverse uc
}
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    print "$_ => ",palin()?"yes":"no","\n";
}
__DATA__
Eva, can I stab bats in a cave?
A man, a plan, a canal. Panama!
Madam, I'm Adam Carolla.
757
Boeing 757
A man, a plan, a big shovel, a canal. Panama!
A man, a plan, a canoe, pasta, heros, rajahs, a coloratura, maps, snipe, percale, macaroni, a gag, a banana bag, a tan, a tag, a banana bag again (or a camel), a crepe, pins, Spam, a rut, a Rolo, cash, a jar, sore hats, a peon, a canal >> __Panama__
```

output:

```
Eva, can I stab bats in a cave? => yes
A man, a plan, a canal. Panama! => yes
Madam, I'm Adam Carolla. => no
757 => yes
Boeing 757 => no
A man, a plan, a big shovel, a canal. Panama! => no
A man, a plan, a canoe, pasta, heros, rajahs, a coloratura, maps, snipe, percale, macaroni, a gag, a banana bag, a tan, a tag, a banana bag again (or a camel), a crepe, pins, Spam, a rut, a Rolo, cash, a jar, sore hats, a peon, a canal >> __Panama__ => yes
```

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it. Though this won't work properly if there's a `_` in the string will it? And it doesn't take any input so won't you need to use the `-p` option?

Comment: `\W` in regexes excludes underscore. I'm afraid you'll need `[^a-z\d]` in your regex. I'm afraid I'm beaten anyways.

Comment: Save one with `_|\W` instead of `[_\W]`.

Comment: You can shorten `_|\W` to `\Pl`: http://ideone.com/0ufdaQ . Should be just the Unicode letters.

Comment: Actually, thinking again - `\Pl` would not match digits, so I guess `_|\W` is the best you could do.

Answer (score 17):

#### C# 82 only :)

```csharp
var x=s.ToLower().Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit);return x.SequenceEqual(x.Reverse());
```

Couldn't resist the temptation of writing a boilerplate-free program in my favorite language.

A test is available here: http://ideone.com/8bwz7z

Comment: Simple...but elegant!

Comment: @AndrewGray thank you for the comment and for the permissive Technical Requirements. C# boilerplate adds seriously to the char count, making it impractical for golf otherwise.

Comment: No prob.  I'm a fellow C# dev, and I like writing concise, efficient code.  It's a shame there's so much boilerplate in the language...

Answer (score 13):

#### GolfScript, <del>36 34 31</del> 30 characters

```
{0"0:A[a{"@{>^}+/},{32|}%.-1%=
```

Similar algorithm to [my previous (Javascript) solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11158/7209).

`0"0:A[a{"@{>^}+/` -- Optimised by Peter Taylor and Howard. My version was `"/9@Z"{1$<},,2%\;`. Howard donated function concatenation and Peter Taylor donated XOR for modulo-2. It's basically a generic method of comparing if the value is in a sequence of ranges.

`{.96>32*-}%` (11 characters) is not really an improvement over Javascript's `.toUpperCase()` (14 characters), especially since it mangles some weird punctuation that follows `z` in the ASCII table (which doesn't matter here).

as Peter Taylor's suggested, however, if we filter out alphanumerics first, we can convert to lowercase and digits just by setting one bit in each character: `{32|}`

`.-1%=` does all the palindromic heavy lifting. One part I'm not really fond of is how long it took me to find out how to reverse an array. I should have read the docs. The other two characters perform stack management and comparison.

Test: http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=IkV2YSwgY2FuIEkgc3RhYiBiYXRzIGluIGEgY2F2ZT8iCgp7IjA6QVtheyJcez59KywsMiV9LHszMnx9JS4tMSU9

---

Further, if I can assume that none of the following control characters are present: (Data link escape, device control 1-4, negative acknowledge, synchronous idle, end of transmission block, cancel, end of medium) (we all agree these are all pretty obscure) or if I can treat them as uppercase versions of the digits 0-9, we can save another two characters:

### GolfScript, 28 characters

```
{32|}%{0"0:a{"@{>^}+/},.-1%=
```

Test: http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=IkV2YSwgY2FuIEkgc3RhYiBiYXRzIGluIGEgY2F2ZT8iCgp7MzJ8fSV7MCIwOmF7IkB7Pl59Ky99LC4tMSU9

Comment: You can get rid of the clean up and save two chars: `{"0:A["\{>}+,,2%},`

Comment: @Howard Thanks. I think I misunderstood `+` on blocks. That's a cool trick.

Comment: You can save three chars by reversing the filter and the case standardisation. You have to add `a{` to the filter's list of characters to include the lower-case letters, but you can then upper-case with just `{32|}%`. The end result is `{"0:A[a{"\{>}+,,2%},{32|}%.-1%=`

Comment: There also another saving to be made on the filter. Counting modulo 2 is xor, so `0"0:A[a{"@{>^}+/` does the job.

Comment: @PeterTaylor If I don't come up with another optimisation myself soon, I probably should convert to community wiki. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 8):

#### Javascript, 53 characters:

```
(x=x.toLowerCase().match(/[a-z\d]/g))+""==x.reverse()
```

is a javascript expression that evaluates to true if `x` is a palindrome, to false if it isn't. It assumes `x` is a string. If that's not guaranteed, prepend `x+="",`

Here's a breadcrumb: Due to how `reverse()` works,

```
(x=x.toLowerCase().match(/[a-z\d]/g))==""+x.reverse()
```

fails. However,

```
""+(x=x.toLowerCase().match(/[a-z\d]/g))==x.reverse()
```

is perfectly fine.

Comment: Nice tidbit on concatenating a null string!  Points for good infoz!

Comment: Hints: `+""` casts to a string, `+` casts to a number, `|0` and `~~` cast to an integer, `!!` casts to a boolean.

Comment: Is a char shorter with regex `/[^\W_]/g`

Answer (score 8):

**Python 2: 49** (without counting the method signature)

```
def f(s):
 s=filter(str.isalnum,s.upper())
 return s==s[::-1]
```

A complete program, with input and output can be writte in **74** characters.

```
import sys
s=filter(str.isalnum,sys.stdin.read().upper())
print s==s[::-1]
```

Example usage:

```
$echo 'Eva,can I stab bats in a cave?' | python palindrome.py
True 
$ cat huge_palindrome.txt | python palindrome.py
True
$echo 'Able was I ere i SaW elBa' | python palindrome.py                                                                   
True
```

(`huge_palindrome.txt` contains [this](http://norvig.com/pal17txt.html) 17,826 word palindrome)

This solution can be adapted to python 3 adding some characters:

**Python 3: 55**

```
def f(s):
 s=list(filter(str.isalnum,s.upper()))
 return s==s[::-1]
```

Comment: `sys.stdin.read` is basically the same as `raw_input`

Comment: In Python 3.8 you can shorten this to [58 bytes](https://tio.run/##FckxCoAwDEDRqzhGqIK4SKEnUYcUKwZqDU0Kevqqf3yfHz2uNE6ca3BLjXj6DZvbglgXSRR2ihoyiOaeBGMqp7n7wvxZ@@WczNZ2w1o5U1IIQImL/q@i8ejxBQ "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: Also, your Python 2 & 3 solution is 61 bytes and 67 bytes, respectively.

Comment: @MilkyWay90 You probably missed the **without counting the method signature**. In 2013 it was customary to not include it. In other solution in this question in other languages they simply omitted it and assumed you have the input in an `s` variable. I decided to provide the complete definition but, as customary in 2013, do not include the method signature in the length

Comment: @Bakuriu Ah, I see. I've only been here a few months, so I don't know customs from 2013

Comment: @Bakuriu So then my solution would be an alternative solution for 49 bytes (not counting the method singature)

Answer (score 8):

## Bash: <s>52</s> <s>48</s> 46 characters

```bash
s=${1,,};s=${s//[^a-z0-9]};[ $s = `rev<<<$s` ]
```

This takes the sting to check as first parameter and sets the exit code to 0 for palindrome and 1 for not.

Sample run:

```
bash-4.2$ p() { s=${1,,};s=${s//[^a-z0-9]};[ $s = `rev<<<$s` ]; }

bash-4.2$ p 'Eva, can I stab bats in a cave?'; echo $?
0

bash-4.2$ p 'A man, a plan, a canal. Panama!'; echo $?
0

bash-4.2$ p "Madam, I'm Adam Corolla."; echo $?
1

bash-4.2$ p '757'; echo $?
0

bash-4.2$ p 'Boeing 757'; echo $?
1

bash-4.2$ p 'A man, a plan, a shovel, a canal. Panama!'; echo $?
1

bash-4.2$ p 'A_man,_a_plan, a_caremer, a canal:_Panama!'; echo $?
0
```

Answer (score 7):

## Mathematica <s>54</s> 53

One byte saved thanks to CatsAreFluffy:

```
PalindromeQ@StringCases[ToUpperCase@#,WordCharacter]&
```

For those with version 10.2 or earlier:

```
#==Reverse@#&@StringCases[ToUpperCase@#,WordCharacter]&
```

**Example**

```
PalindromeQ@StringCases[ToUpperCase@#, WordCharacter]&["Eva,can I stab bats in a cave?"]
```

> True

Comment: `PalindromeQ` is 1 byte shorter than `#==Reverse@#&`

Comment: I wondered why I had never seen it. Version 10.3!

Comment: `PalindromeQ= #==Reverse@#&`

Comment: Yes, I downloaded v. 10.4 to try it out.

Comment: That's out? OHNO

Answer (score 7):

**JAVA (or the most verbose language ever), <del>102</del> <del>96</del> 95 char**

```
s=s.replaceAll("\\W|_","");return s.equalsIgnoreCase(new StringBuffer(s).reverse().toString());
```

Usage (with ungolfed code):

```
static boolean q(String s) {
    s=s.replaceAll("\\W|_","");
    return s.equalsIgnoreCase(new StringBuffer(s).reverse().toString());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(q("'A man, a plan, a canal - Panama!'"));
}
```

Shortened with the help of the commenter below

Comment: While I don't know Java (I'm a C# guy, funny enough), couldn't you save 1 character by taking out the curly braces on the if?  E.G.: `if(s==null) return 1==0;`?  Or does Java enforce curlies on `if` statements?

Comment: You are absolutely right, I took that out thank you!!... I haven't notice they were there, I guess I'm a Java developer that doesn't C#?

Comment: 1) Checking whether the parameter is `null` is a good habit, but not practiced in CodeGolf. As I can tell, nobody else did it in this question. Skip it. 2) The space between arguments helps readability, but not golfing. Remove it; 3) Instead of explicitly `toLowerCase()` the string use `equalsIgnoreCase()` later instead of `equals()`. This way you have to adjust the regular expression, but still 1 character shorter. http://pastebin.com/s7H84faj

Comment: `replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]","")` => `replaceAll("\\W","")`

Comment: Actually: `replaceAll("\\W|_","");` to remove `_` too => 95 characters

Comment: I know this has been answered more than three years ago, but you can golf two more things: `.toString()` can be `+""`, and you can make it a one-lined to save another byte like this: `return(s=s.replaceAll("\\W|_","")).equalsIgnoreCase(new StringBuffer(s).reverse()+"");` (**86 bytes**)

Answer (score 7):

### R: 66

```
w=grep("[a-z0-9]",strsplit(tolower(s),"")[[1]],v=T);all(w==rev(w))
```

Usage:

```
f=function(s){w=grep("[a-z0-9]",strsplit(tolower(s),"")[[1]],v=T);all(w==rev(w))}

f("Eva, can I stab bats in a cave?")
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 6):

## k (<s>50 48 45</s> 38 chars)

Suppresses all errors, returning a default of `0b` (false).

```
{X~|X@:&(X:_:x)in 10h$(48+!10),97+!26}
```

Example:

```
k){X~|X@:&(X:_:x)in 10h$(48+!10),97+!26} "Eva, can I stab bats in a cave?"
1b
```

edit: shaved three more character by avoiding intermediate variable. H/T, CS. -7: No need to suppress errors.

Comment: interesting that at just 3 characters more, my code is much more readable :-)

Comment: An extra char slipped in, I have removed it.

Answer (score 6):

### J, 30 characters

```
*/(=|.)tolower(#~'[^_\W]'rxE])
```

Usage:

```
   */(=|.)tolower(#~'[^_\W]'rxE])'A man, a plan, a canal - Panama!'
1
   */(=|.)tolower(#~'[^_\W]'rxE])'Doc, note: I dissent. A fast never prevents a fatness. I diet on cod'
1
```

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby: <s>43</s> 38 characters

```ruby
s=s.upcase.tr'^A-Z0-9','';s==s.reverse
```

Sample run:

```
irb(main):001:0> p=->s{s=s.upcase.tr'^A-Z0-9','';s==s.reverse}
=> #<Proc:0x854592c@(irb):1 (lambda)>

irb(main):002:0> p['Eva, can I stab bats in a cave?']
=> true

irb(main):003:0> p['A man, a plan, a canal. Panama!']
=> true

irb(main):004:0> p["Madam, I'm Adam Corolla."]
=> false

irb(main):005:0> p['757']
=> true

irb(main):006:0> p['Boeing 757']
=> false

irb(main):007:0> p['A man, a plan, a shovel, a canal. Panama!']
=> false

irb(main):009:0> p['A_man,_a_plan, a_caremer, a canal:_Panama!']
=> true
```

Comment: You can even write `s.tr!('^A-Za-z0-9','').upcase!.reverse==s`

Comment: Man, how long I combined around the use of the `!` methods! You keep amazing me @Howard with your tricks.

Comment: Small problem though, @Howard. `tr` and `tr!` seems to behave different when they have nothing to transliterate: http://pastebin.com/4YThW2qN That makes the `p['757']` test to crash with “NoMethodError: undefined method `upcase!' for nil:NilClass” error.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Didn't think about that case.

Comment: can be shortened further: `s=s.upcase.tr('^A-Z0-9','');s==s.reverse`

Comment: Ouch! What a stupid miss. Thank you, @w0lf. Event better, this way the parenthesis are not necessary anymore.

Comment: My version is `s=s.upcase.gsub /\W/,'';s==s.reverse` which. is 3 chars shorter.

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier, according to my counting, that is only 2 characters shorter. And if you make it to work correctly by excluding underscores from the comparison, `s=s.upcase.gsub /\W|_/,'';s==s.reverse` will be 0 characters shorter.

Answer (score 5):

## C++, <del>107</del> (miscounted), <del>100</del> (miscounted), 81

```
string s;for(int c:t)if(isalnum(c))s+=c|32;return s==string(s.rbegin(),s.rend());
```

- Exploits ASCII bit patterns.
- Relies on an evil `using namespace std;`.
- Uses bitwise AND and OR instead of the logical operators.
- Uses `int` because it's shorter than `char` or `auto`.

  ```
  #include <string>
  using namespace std;

  bool IsPalindrome(const string & t) {
  string s;for(int c:t)if(isalnum(c))s+=c|32;return s==string(s.rbegin(),s.rend());
  }

  #include <cassert>

  int main() {
      assert(!IsPalindrome("gorilla"));  // simple failure
      assert( IsPalindrome("racecar"));  // simple success
      assert( IsPalindrome("Hannah"));   // case blind
      assert(!IsPalindrome("1999"));     // digit failure
      assert( IsPalindrome("2002"));     // digit success
      // Ignore spacing, punctuation, and case:
      assert( IsPalindrome(" \t09AZ/:@[`{za90"));  // boundaries
      assert( IsPalindrome("A man, a plan, a canal: Panama."));
      assert( IsPalindrome("Eva, can I stab bats in a cave?"));
      assert( IsPalindrome(""));  // empty string
      return 0;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 4):

## Lua, 56

```
a=io.read"*l":lower():gsub("%W","")print(a:reverse()==a)
```

Comment: If `%W` is anything like `\W` in regex, it also excludes characters like underscore. This is unwanted.

Comment: i checked, `%w` doesn't include `_` (`%W` obviously includes it, then)

Comment: Only function body is needed.  `s=s:lower():gsub('%W','')return s:reverse()==s`  46 chars

Comment: but what about `function(s)`

Answer (score 4):

**Python 3/2 59 chars:**

```
def pld(i):
   p=[c for c in i.lower() if c.isalnum()]
   return(p == p[::-1])
```

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, 43

Using the standard libraries `Control.Monad`, `Control.Monad.Instances`, and `Data.Char`:

```
ap(==)reverse.map toLower.filter isAlphaNum
```

Comment: I can't make this to work in ghci.
`import Data.Char`
`import Control.Monad`
`ap(==)reverse.map toLower.filter isAlphaNum`
neither does it with adding spaces or such, sorry I'm not too keen with Haskell :)

Comment: @SlimJim: Oops, you need `Control.Monad.Instances` as well. (I’m using the Reader monad instance with `ap`, but that instance isn’t exported by `Control.Monad`.)

Answer (score 4):

**PHP 60 characters.**

First try on codegolf.

```
//thank you manatwork
echo($x=preg_replace('/\W/','',strtolower($c)))==strrev($x);
```

Example:

```
$c='Eva, can I stab bats in a cave?';
echo($x=preg_replace('/\W/','',strtolower($c)))==strrev($x);
//prints 1
```

Comment: The parenthesis around the ternary operator's first operand are not needed. Actually neither the ternary operator is needed – just output true or false in your language's representation. And by avoiding the separate statement for the assignment to $x 1 more character can be shortened: `echo($x=preg_replace('/\W/','',strtolower($c)))==strrev($x);`.

Answer (score 3):

**Python 2 64 Charecters:**

```
i =''.join(re.findall('[a-z0-9]+',i.lower()))
return i==i[::-1]
```

Comment: @manatwork If you replace all the identifiers with one character identifiers you obtain a `77` characters version. No idea why abhiram posted the ungolfed version though.

Comment: @Bakuriu, never mind, I missed one statement in the question: “Only method bodies are needed”. Though lines 2 and 3 gives me only 73 characters. Regarding further length reduction, no need for raw string and the capture group, making the `re.findall('[a-z0-9]+',input.lower())` part 3 characters shorter.

Comment: @manatwork, I edited the post and changed the variables a little. That brought it down to 66. 
Yes, the raw string attribute is of no use here.

Comment: Ok, but why you insist on the capturing group in the regular expression? Works correctly without: http://pastebin.com/JzpNRRZU

Comment: I think it caught on with me after my recent python project involving re's :)
Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell 48

```
(\x->x==reverse x).map toLower.filter isAlphaNum
```

used like this:

```
(\x->x==reverse x).map toLower.filter isAlphaNum$"Eva, can I stab bats in a cave?"
```

Answer (score 3):

**Smalltalk**, Squeak/Pharo flavour
**116** chars using traditional formatting with tabs

You add two methods to String:

```
selffles
    ^self = self reverse
isPalindrome
    ^(self asUppercase asDecomposedUnicode select: #isAlphaNumeric) selffles
```

We could of course eliminate some spaces, or use shorter method names, but let's not betray the spirit of Smalltalk.

More over, this will handle French palindromes, like in http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_de_palindromes_fran%C3%A7ais, not many answers in this page can.

```
['Léon a trop par rapport à Noël' isPalindrome] assert.
```

Comment: Clever and useful answer!

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3 (51 char)

#### and may be Python 2

based on *abhiram* solution (with more agressive golfing)

```
from re import findall

def palindrome(i):
 i=findall('[a-z\d]',i.lower())
 return i==i[::-1]

print(palindrome(input('Phrase: ')))
```

may be shortened to 46 chars, using RE '\w'

and variant with extremely shortened function body (27 chars)

```
import re
l=str.lower
f=re.compile('[a-z\d]').findall

def palindrome(i):i=f(l(i));return i==i[::-1]

print(palindrome(input('Phrase: ')))
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 63 bytes

```julia
~s=((x=filter(in(['0':'9';'A':'Z']),uppercase(s)))==reverse(x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYqxDoIwFEVn@YoXlrYJMQ@VQU2jDg5uzhqH11pjDRbSAjLx65XF4HTPObmvtrSU9zEOQXLey4ctG@O5dfzKkG3Ymm3ZYdwLu4msrWvjNQXDgxBCSm8640frhYj78Kw@MKTHjjLQ5OAEoSEFipoA1gGNsTO7NPkdz1Rad/fV20ytyBARcI5YTDFfLFd/OhEpDTDTitIkfgE)

Since punctuation is filtered out, `"5,000 0.005"` is considered a palindrome.

Answer (score 2):

### Windows PowerShell, <strike>56</strike> <strike>47</strike> 45 chars

Updated (see comments), and can remove the brackets around the regex:

```
($s=$s-replace'\W')-eq(-join$s[$s.length..0])
```

Original (56)

```
$s=$s-replace'[^\w]','';$s-eq($s[-1..-$s.length]-join'')
```

Original Un-golfed:

```
$s = "Eva, can I stab bats in a cave?"
$s = $s -replace '[^\w]', ''
$rev = $s[-1..-$s.length] -join ''
$s -eq $rev
```

Comment: You can golf this down to 47 chars like this: `($s=$s-replace'[\W]')-eq(-join$s[$s.length..0])`

Comment: @SpellingD: Nice! I'm new at code golfing, thanks for the improvement

Comment: you can remove the right parenthesis also: `($s=$s-replace'\W')-eq-join$s[$s.length..0]`.

Answer (score 2):

## C++, 74 bytes

This code is actually really elegant, and easy to understand (when formatted correctly). I don't believe it's possible to get any shorter in C++, and it doesn't use any standard library functions.

```
p(auto c){auto e=c;while(*e)++e;--e;while(*e==*c&e>c)--e,++c;return e<=c;}
```

Example usage:

```
p("Hello"); //Outputs 0
p(""); //Outputs 1
p("a"); //Outputs 1
p("HellolleH"); //Outputs 1
```

Nicely formatted version:

```
p(auto c)
{
    auto e=c;
    while(*e) ++e;
    --e;
    while(*e==*c & e>c)--e,++c;
    return e<=c;
}
```

Comment: `error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘p’ with no type` your function should have a return type.

Comment: I bet this does not ignore case, whitespace and control characters.

Comment: You can save a character with `while(*++e);` instead of `while(*e)++e;`. But as Titus mentioned this answer is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>26 84 80 78 62</s> 63 bytes

```php
<?=strrev($s=strtolower(preg_replace("#\W#","",$argv[1])))==$s;
```

takes input from first command line argument; prints `1` for truthy, empty string for falsy.

---

I18n is a littly expansive, as there is no multibyte alternative for `strrev` (110 bytes; run with `-r`):

```php
preg_match_all("#.#us",$s=strtolower(preg_replace("#\W#u","",$argv[1])),$m);echo$s==join(array_reverse($m[0]);
```

utf8_strrev blatantly [stolen from the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php#83461). You might also want to take a look at [this blog post](http://kvz.io/blog/2012/10/09/reverse-a-multibyte-string-in-php/).

Comment: Come on Titus... This fails the spec.

Comment: @Christoph Yeah I sometimes should fully read that. Fixed.

Comment: Hm `-R` would cause problems with line breaks in the string to test wouldn't it? From the spec " -R <code>  Run PHP <code> for every input line". Moreover `<?=strrev($s=strtolower(preg_replace("#\W#","",$argn)))==$s;`would be shorter.

Comment: @Christoph Nice idea, but there is no `$argn` without `-R`.

Comment: `$argv[1]="O Genie, der Herr ehre dein Ego!"; # :D`

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 18 bytes

```
#|:\(2!"0:a{"')__:
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJyFUE1PwkAQve+vGKuJkNDWtnDZHgyJHrwY70hgaKewod3F3ZFAUH+7Uwx69LJv533M7E6jrz/06yC/iu40nqLb4WKhlWJ9upkdv7xuAOBQLt22HCwbNG15KI+lH84/xTOLHvc4ggotPEFgXMEKOYCxgELu6T4qs3lve3Ys1A5bY2vvul7Iz8IUOrSjXmt/UHphq+FFoMNL/MFVI7COScuc2oRAlhOYQoOBwdKePOy8gJXhKCxbCiE5e4nBWahcfemV5UWeXQpELIpCzl9iPD4/TaVqw7wLOk0lS2vXNol8sNrSodqgXVNSuS59e6fAxtmQZlk2maRh4zwLFfeZmF1cE5PvjKXYNDHGgb2x69gEuf8tQ6l/16jUN9xbhXo=)

Uses @scrawl's suggestion [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11155/shortest-code-to-determine-if-a-string-is-a-palindrome?page=2&tab=modifieddesc#comment463731_11166) to return `1` for palindromes and `2` for non-palindromes. If `1` and `0` are required, the solution can be adjusted by prefixing `1=`.

- `_:` lowercase the (implicit) input
- `(...)_` filter out values where the code in `(...)` returns a non-0 value

  - `2!"0:a{"'` do a bins lookup, then mod the result by two; returns `0` if the input is within `"a"-"z"` or `"0"-"9"` and `1` otherwise
- `|:\` set up a converge-scan, reversing the input until the original input is returned. on palindromes, returns a one-item list; on non-palindromes, a two-item list
- `#` take the count of the result from above. As noted, if a strict `1` and `0` output are required for palindrome/non-palindrome, prefix `1=` for two bytes

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 48

```
p((g=gets.upcase.gsub /[^A-Z\d]/,'')==g.reverse)
```

Quite simple, and hastily made so not golfed too much. I shall golf it more later.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pylongolf2](https://github.com/lvivtotoro/pylongolf2), 24 bytes

```
c╨2"[^a-zA-Z]"-_╨1=~
```

`c` takes the input, `╨2` to convert to lower case.
I then push a regex onto the stack and use `-` to remove all non-alphabetical characters in the input.
`_` duplicates the input.
`╨1` reverses it and `=` then compares them.
`~` prints the stack in the end which prints either `true` or `false`.

Comment: Does this ignore the punctuation, whitespace and control characters?

Comment: My bad, this version does not.
I will fix it.

Comment: Fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, <s>194</s> 190 bytes

A recursive implementation to show how an unnamed PowerShell scriptblock can call itself.

```
$P={param([string]$s)$s=($s-replace'[^a-z]').tolower();if(!$s){return $true};if($s.length-lt4){return $s[0]-eq$s[-1]};$s[0]-eq$s[-1]-and(&$MyInvocation.MyCommand.ScriptBlock $s.trim($s[0]))}
```

ungolfed:

```
$P={
param([string]$s)
$s=($s-replace'[^a-z]').tolower();
if(!$s){return $true};
if($s.length-lt4){return $s[0]-eq$s[-1]};
$s[0]-eq$s[-1]-and(&$MyInvocation.MyCommand.ScriptBlock $s.trim($s[0]))
}
```

tests:

```
&$P "Eva, can I stab bats in a cave?"
&$P "Eva, can I stab cats in a cave?"
&$P "A man, a plan, a canal. Panama!"
&$P "A man, a plan, a big shovel, a canal. Panama!"
&$P "Madam, I'm Adam."
&$P "Madam, I'm Adam Corolla."
&$P "757"
&$P "Boeing 757"
```

Comment: Shouldn´t that be `[^a-z0-9]`?

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
álÂQ
```

Explanation:

```
á     # Only keep the alphabetic characters.
 l    # Lowercase the characters.
  Â   # Bifurcate, which duplicates the letters and reverses the duplicate.
   Q  # Check if they are equal.
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=w6Fsw4JR&input=RXZhLCBjYW4gSSBzdGFiIGJhdHMgaW4gYSBjYXZl).

Comment: Tried to run it via your link. Program output is "1"

Answer (score 1):

## Jelly, 10 Characters

```
fØBŒl
UÇ⁼Ç
```

Returns 1 if true, 0 if false

[Try it Online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=ZsOYQsWSbApVw4figbzDhw&input=&args=RXZhLCBjYW4gSSBzdGFiIGJhdHMgaW4gYSBjYXZlPw)

Comment: Does it ignore case, whitespace and control characters? A breakdown would be nice.

Comment: The current state of Jelly allows for solving this in 7 bytes: [`fØBŒlŒḂ`](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@592eIbT0Uk5Ryc93NH0//9/17JEHYXkxDwFT4XiipLEJIWkxJJihcw8hUSgaFmqPQA): `f` filter to keep `ØB` the set [a-zA-Z0-9] and `Œl` convert to lowercase, then `ŒḂ` test if palindrome.

Answer (score 1):

## Racket, 132 bytes

Pretty embarrassing, but maybe somebody can see a way of making this shorter!

```rkt
((λ(l[n(floor(/(length l)2))])(equal?(take l n)(take(reverse l)n)))(string->list(regexp-replace*"[^0-9a-z]"(string-downcase s)"")))
```

#### Code listing with test module

```rkt
#lang racket

(define/contract (palindrome? s)
  (string? . -> . boolean?)
  ((λ(l[n(floor(/(length l)2))])(equal?(take l n)(take(reverse l)n)))(string->list(regexp-replace*"[^0-9a-z]"(string-downcase s)""))))

(module+ test
  (require rackunit)
  (define tests
    '(("Eva, can I stab bats in a cave?" . #t)
      ("A man, a plan, a canal. Panama!" . #t)
      ("Madam, I'm Adam Corolla." . #f)
      ("757" . #t)
      ("Boeing 757" . #f)
      ("A man, a plan, a big shovel, a canal. Panama!" . #f)
      ("A man, a plan, a canoe, pasta, heros, rajahs, a coloratura, maps, snipe, percale, macaroni, a gag, a banana bag, a tan, a tag, a banana bag again (or a camel), a crepe, pins, Spam, a rut, a Rolo, cash, a jar, sore hats, a peon, a canal >> __Panama__" . #t)))
  (for ([t tests])
    (check-equal? (palindrome? (car t)) (cdr t) (~a t))))
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL, <s>78</s> 65 Bytes

```
l←⎕D,⎕UCS v+32⊣c←⎕D,⎕UCS v←64+⍳26⋄(⌽≡⊢)∊{⍵/⍨⍵∊l}¨{⍵∊c:l[c⍳⍵]⋄⍵}¨⎕
```

I'm going to assume that the Original Poster meant limit the INPUT string to the Ascii character set.

Answer (score 1):

## C++14, 104 bytes

Actually overlooked the requirement to ignore case and whitespace, so here is:

```c++
auto f=
[](auto s,int&n){
auto r=s.rbegin();n=1;for(auto c:s){if(isalnum(c)){while(!isalnum(*r))r++;if((c|32)!=(*(r++)|32))n=0;}}
}
;
```

## strict solution, <s>72</s> 68 bytes

-4 bytes for returning by parameter.

As unnamed lambda, assuming input `s` is of type `std::string` and returning the result by a parameter:

```c++
[](auto s,int&n){auto r=s.rbegin();n=1;for(auto c:s)if(c!=*r++)n=0;}
```

Ungolfed & usage:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

auto f=
[](auto s, int& n){
  auto r=s.rbegin();
  n=1;
  for(auto c:s)
    if(c!=*r++)
      n=0;
}
;

int main(){
int n;
#define p(s) f(std::string(s),n); std::cout << n << std::endl
 p("Hello");
 p("ABCCBA");
 p("ABCBA");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2.7.6, 79 bytes

"Sorry I don't get what characters to count so I wrote the whole program"

```
import re
n=raw_input()
n=re.sub("[^a-z]+","",n.lower())
print n==n[::-1]
```

> This will print **True** if input string is palindrome else
> **False**.

Code_link: http://ideone.com/b4NzLD

Answer (score 1):

### REXX, 84 bytes

```
arg n
n=space(translate(n,,translate(n,,xrange(a,z)xrange(0,9))),0)
say n=reverse(n)
```

`arg n` 
reads argument into variable `n`, converting it to upper-case.

`xrange(a,z)xrange(0,9)` concatenates the two ranges A—Z and 0—9.

`translate` takes a string to process, an output translation table and an input translation table, and optionally a padding character to replace those characters not found in the output table with. Hence 
`translate(n,,xrange(a,z)xrange(0,9))` maps the string `n` with an input table consisting only of alphanumerical characters and an empty output table, resulting in a string consisting only of punctuation, spaces and other non-alphanumericals (since they were not in either table). The filtered-out characters are rendered as spaces.

`translate(n,,translate(n,,xrange(a,z)xrange(0,9)))` uses the above non-alphanumerics string as an input table and an empty output table, applying it to `n`, resulting in a string consisting only of alphanumericals, since they were not in the input or output tables. The non-alphanumerics are rendered as spaces.

`space()` takes a string and a number, spacing out the words with the supplied amount of spaces between. In this case, the supplied number is `0`, hence all spaces are removed.

By this point, `n` has been reduced to consisting only of alphanumeric characters without any spaces.

`say n=reverse(n)` prints out whether `n` is identical to its reversed version.

Answer (score 1):

## Dyalog APL (18 characters)

```
 {⍵≡⌽⍵}'\w'⎕S'\u0'⊢
```

Search for alphanumeric characters in the right argument, and return any found upper-cased (this avoids any need for punctuation, whitespace and casing). Then just check what's returned to see if it matches the reverse.

### Example

```
{⍵≡⌽⍵}'\w'⎕S'\u0'⊢'Eva, can I stab bats in a cave?'
    1
```

Comment: This is a snippet. The (tacit) function is `{⍵≡⌽⍵}'\w'⎕S'\u0'` which can be named (or parenthesised) before application. Also, you can save another byte by replacing `{⍵≡⌽⍵}` with `(⊢≡⌽)`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
kr↔⇩Ḃ=  #
```

```
kr      # push the upper and lowercase alphabet
  ↔⇩    # remove all chars in input that are not in that, and lowercase
    Ḃ   # push a and a.reverse()
     =  # equal?
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=kB%E2%86%94%E2%87%A9%E1%B8%82%3D&inputs=Eva%2C%20can%20I%20stab%20bats%20in%20a%20cave%3F&header=&footer=)

Comment: This ignores numbers in the input, so you need to [replace kB with kr](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?flags=&code=kr%E2%86%94%E2%87%A9%E1%B8%82%3D&inputs=321Eva%2C%20can%20I%20stab%20bats%20in%20a%20cave%3F12&header=&footer=) to make sure numbers get counted.

Comment: @AaronMiller Ah, I misread that as numbers are not counted, fixed

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
LỊḲ⁼
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#P2hlYWRlcj0mY29kZT1MJUUxJUJCJThBJUUxJUI4JUIyJUUyJTgxJUJDJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9RXZhJTJDJTIwY2FuJTIwSSUyMHN0YWIlMjBiYXRzJTIwaW4lMjBhJTIwY2F2ZSUzRiZmbGFncz0=)

##### Explanation

```python
LỊḲ⁼  # Implicit input
L     # Convert to lowercase
 Ị    # Only keep alphabetic characters
  Ḳ   # Duplicate and reverse
   ⁼  # Are they equal?
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift, <strike>82</strike> 77 bytes

```swift
let t=s.lowercased().replacing(/[\W_]/,with:"");return Array(t)==t.reversed()
```

Where `s` is a `String` argument. I think it's rather self-explanatory — that's the beauty of Swift.

Comment: Shaved off 5 bytes by using a regex and a call to `replacing(_:with:)`.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript Code  :: ONLY  140 characters
      
      
      Palindrome

```
function palindrome()
{
    var user=prompt("Enter the characters to check the palindrome");
    var split=user.split('').reverse().join(''); // ONLY this line counts 
    if(user == split)
    {
        alert("The given word is a Palindrome");
    } else
    {
        alert("The given word is not a Palindrome");
    }

}
```

palindrome();

Comment: Erm...afraid not, the comparison is also part of checking that a string is a palindrome.

Comment: oh... Sorry.. Then its takes 140 characters..

Comment: The requirement says you need to ignore uppercase vs. lowercase differences and punctuation.

Comment: Additionally, don't worry about the method signature.  We're just worried with how you solve the problem, not language-specific boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

### Racket 118 bytes

```
(let((l(filter(λ(x)(or(char-alphabetic? x)(char-numeric? x)))(string->list(string-upcase s)))))(equal? l(reverse l)))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (palindrome? s)
  (let((l(filter(λ(x)(or(char-alphabetic? x)
                        (char-numeric? x)))
                (string->list (string-upcase s)))))
    (equal? l(reverse l))))
```

Testing:

```
(palindrome? "abc  dcB;_A")
(palindrome? "abc;@#$zdc b  a")
(palindrome? "1%^&234 56")
(palindrome? "1a234 * ^ && 565432A1")
```

Output:

```
#t
#f
#f
#t
```

Comment: This is neither case insensitive and nor does it ignore punctuation, control characters and whitespace.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I have corrected the code above.

Answer (score 0):

## AHK, 83 bytes <sup><sup><sup><sup>(L7 loser)</sup></sup></sup></sup>

```
StringUpper,s,1
s:=RegExReplace(s,"[\W_]")
Loop,Parse,s
t:=A_LoopField t
Send % s=t
```

Outputs `1` for palindromes and `0` for not.

Answer (score 0):

**C, 199 bytes**

```
#define R return
#define C unsigned char
#define F for
s(C*a){C*b;if(a&&*a)F(b=a+strlen(a)-1;;++a,--b){F(;a<b&&!isalnum(*a);)++a;F(;a<b&&!isalnum(*b);)--b;if(a>=b)R 1;if((*a|32)-(*b|32))R 0;}R 1;}
```

//ungolf

```
v(C*a)
{ C*b;
 if(a&&*a)
   F(b=a+strlen(a)-1;;++a,--b)
           {F(;a<b&&!isalnum(*a);)++a;
            F(;a<b&&!isalnum(*b);)--b;
            if(a>=b)           R 1;
            if((*a|32)-(*b|32))R 0;
           }
 R 1;
}

#define P printf
main()
{C*b="Eva, can I stab bats in a cave?";
 P("%s %d\n", b, s(b));
 R 0;
}
```

//results

```
//Eva, can I stab bats in a cave? 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, <s>72</s> 65 bytes

```
(let((y(remove-if-not'alphanumericp(read))))(equalp(reverse y)y))
```

*-7 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat !*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYxBCsMwDAS/4uZSCZoP9NYf9AdCuCo1yIrqOAG/3tFeZpeBzVp2n@CtWJ@g0gEGNKnbKWv5rrb1O6v/2I4qrWQPxx@MgPyPMLFPabukgQNx4lxeVNkexOQaTEyZ409a1JTZWJ/0DlS@LRc)

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 31 bytes

```
\W

T`l`L
+`^(.)(.*)\1$
$2
^.?$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/JpyLKyQhJ8GHSzshTkNPU0NPSzPGUIVLxYgrTs9e5f9/17JEHYXkxDwFT4XiksQkhaTEkmKFzDyFRKBgWao9AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [QuadS](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS), 19 bytes

Equivalent to [James Heslip's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136604/43319).

```apl
⍵≡⌽⍵
\w
\u&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyxNTCn@//9R79ZHnQsf9ewFMrhiyrliStX@/3ctS9RRSE7MU/BUKC5JTFJISiwpVsjMU0gECpal2gMA)

*Is…*

`⍵≡⌽⍵` the text identical to its reverse

`\w` after finding all word characters

`\u&` and uppercasing them

*?*

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 118 bytes

```c
p(s,n)char*s,*n;{char*r=s+strlen(s)-1;for(*n=1;*s;s++)if(isalnum(*s)){for(;!isalnum(*r);r--);*n*=(*s|32)==(*r--|32);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY2xboMwEIb3PMUVKZXP2EPa0aKdMmTv2MVxTGMJDvA5WSjPTg1BkXrTf999ut/pH@fmuResCN3VRslKkhnXGCsuOcXGk2DUB1N3UUiqDkay4bLEUIvAtqFbKyQjjsvdvDxRRBO1RiNJVln4fX/DKofMlmimaU6ek1irBhx3kCdQguj51iSz7r0Y1OsD4EZidmpR7Bn0B@wv31QoGBQ8pWnX2kBie7hWFMe7VeAswQk42TOcbeLcBTbDu/8stt8P@esa8pGBupSF3jaBLrFr/X9r2ab5Dw)

Used like: `p(string, &result);`; outputs by modifying `result`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
k\W v
¶Ô
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=a1xXIHYKttQ&input=IkV2YSwgY2FuIEkgc3RhYiBiYXRzIGluIGEgY2F2ZT8i)

```
k\W v\n¶Ô     :Implicit input of string U
k             :Remove
 \W           :  RegEx /[^a-z0-9/gi
    v         :Lowercase
     \n       :Reassign to U
       ¶      :Is equal to
        Ô     :Reverse
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n=>n.split('').reverse().join('')==n;
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Code Golf. This doesn't account for the fact that punctuation doesn't count towards palindrominess.

Comment: You are also missing the byte count in the header

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 42 bytes

```sh
s=${(L)1//[^A-Za-z0-9]}
<<<${s/`rev<<<$s`}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1RS8MwEMff@ynOGWgC7brKpDo6RxUfBgo@K5reYmYHSTOaUWGln71LNueLPt3d/373u72thjVl3WDnpKNPLE2St48ifsV4P4lv3/sgz3PS2aRsZOtbW/ZDH2zdRQAgRWWApECu3IBzQr8FxMJh5foUl8wtjgZ6yQileJcussnsZspYHzgNhI8tRiCwhiXYHa5ghTsLmxrQha1chJ4pQGMduWirTtXxqMbw4orGC8@MnvETdQTLUEPhOngwjVEKxyMvyK6zo@jeyE39Befxj9dWppXq/w9hwT3Nkf/QXGAjtWx@8Rk/48MB)

Truthy (palindrome) is empty string, falsy otherwise. TIO link includes a test harness that outputs `T` or `F`.